# Change the user input on django change form before sending it to the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model that has a uuid representing a certain region. There is a short name for the regions and their respective uuid, this is stored in a csv currently. Is there a way to allow an admin to use the short name instead of the uuid when editing a record, but the uuid is what is actually used in the database?

Current:
[Current edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdeUB.png)

Desired:
[Desired edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGgms.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use lookup for your project in this way you create table database or CSV file for lookup (UUID,short name)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).